# Parsing smileys with text as string to html and keeping smileys in order in display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I checked out some of the suggestions but i could not find anything that related to keeping smileys in order in the text.

My situation is that the string is perfect from php to js (via ajax) and then it is passed to this function below. At this point the string looks like this

```
  hello this is a test <a href="javascript:void(0);"><img onclick="addcodesmiley('newmessage',':cry:');return false;" class="smileyeach" src="https://example.com/ow_static/plugins/chat/images/icon_cry.gif" alt="cry" /></a> of the smokey bear <a href="javascript:void(0);"><img onclick="addcodesmiley('newmessage',':mad:');return false;"  class="smileyeach" src="https://example.com/ow_static/plugins/chat/images/icon_mad.gif" alt="mad" /></a> ok then
```

Which is in the order that i want IE  text smiley text smiley

But when it leaves js and gets to html it changes order to smiley smiley text

I think from my reading that it has something to do with using innerHTML because the images dont have innerHTML.  I have read alittle about parsing using DOM and also jquery but honestly im not sure if thats the issue or not and i dont want to end up chasing my tail here.

Here is the function im using to post the data to html, again at this stage it is in the right order. And other than the order changing to ()() text everything else works fine.

So why is the order changing?  And what would i look into to learn how to correct it?

```
  function postchat(userinfo, mess, thetime) 
  {

   /* create the dynamic table cells */
   var chattable = document.getElementById("showChat");
   var row = chattable.insertRow(0);
   var userdat = row.insertCell(0);
   var umsg = row.insertCell(1);
   var mtim = row.insertCell(2);

   /* load the cells */  
   userdat.innerHTML = userinfo;
   umsg.innerHTML = mess;
   mtim.innerHTML = thetime;

   /* set the class for cells */
   userdat.className = 'uinfo';
   umsg.className = 'mess';
   mtim.className = 'when';

   /* move scroll bar down with text */
   updateScroll();

 }//close function postchat
```

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved it was in my CSS

The first cell in the table is the avatar and the username that had a class of

```
 .uinfo {
  width:20%;
  padding-left: 0px;
  text-align: left;
 }
```

when i first set this up i wanted to push the avatar over a bit so i added

```
 img {
 float: left;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 }
```

which did not limit it to the first cell but all images...  So when i added the smileys i forgot to go in and limit that to just that cell.

so i just had to change it to this

```
 .uinfo img {
 float: left;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 }
```

problem solved......  the answer was outside the box and i never considered CSS as the solution. Mainly because my head is still in the old days i guess when CSS was in the HTML and when i dont see it i dont think about it.  It should be more top of mind and i learned a lesson here.